# How to match over multiple lines in Perl when reading input from the pipe

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract data from log files. 
That data span over multiple lines.
The starting line contains a timestamp, a thread id, and some other relevant attributes.
The ending line contains the thread id and a elapsed time how long that thread worked was busy.
The results should be written into a CVS file for statistical analysis.
Each result row should look like: timestamp of the starting line, thread id, the other relevant attributes and the elapsed time.

A 'rearranged' log snipped looks like follows:

```
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | Received message with id 1234 - com.example.product.module.Receiver#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | some log message #1 - com.example.product.module.Helper1#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | some log message #2 - com.example.product.module.Helper2#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | some log message #3 - com.example.product.module.Helper3#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | some log message #4 - com.example.product.module.Helper4#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.224 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | Message processed in 101ms - com.example.product.module.Receiver#130

2015-08-01 12:24:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | Received message with id 2345 - com.example.product.module.Receiver#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | some log message #1 - com.example.product.module.Helper1#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | some log message #2 - com.example.product.module.Helper2#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | some log message #3 - com.example.product.module.Helper3#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | some log message #4 - com.example.product.module.Helper4#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.225 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | Message processed in 102ms - com.example.product.module.Receiver#130

2015-08-01 12:25:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | Received message with id 3456 - com.example.product.module.Receiver#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | some log message #1 - com.example.product.module.Helper1#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | some log message #2 - com.example.product.module.Helper2#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | some log message #3 - com.example.product.module.Helper3#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | some log message #4 - com.example.product.module.Helper4#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.226 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | Message processed in 103ms - com.example.product.module.Receiver#130
```

But in reality those log messages are mixed, as the application runns multiple threads at the same time. So the real log looks like:

```
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | Received message with id 1234 - com.example.product.module.Receiver#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | some log message #1 - com.example.product.module.Helper1#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | some log message #2 - com.example.product.module.Helper2#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | Received message with id 2345 - com.example.product.module.Receiver#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | some log message #3 - com.example.product.module.Helper3#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | some log message #1 - com.example.product.module.Helper1#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | Received message with id 3456 - com.example.product.module.Receiver#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | some log message #1 - com.example.product.module.Helper1#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | some log message #2 - com.example.product.module.Helper2#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | some log message #2 - com.example.product.module.Helper2#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | some log message #4 - com.example.product.module.Helper4#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.123 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | some log message #3 - com.example.product.module.Helper3#123
2015-08-01 12:23:21.224 | DEBUG | Thread-10 | Message processed in 101ms - com.example.product.module.Receiver#130
2015-08-01 12:24:21.224 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | some log message #4 - com.example.product.module.Helper4#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.224 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | some log message #3 - com.example.product.module.Helper3#123
2015-08-01 12:25:21.224 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | some log message #4 - com.example.product.module.Helper4#123
2015-08-01 12:24:21.225 | DEBUG | Thread-11 | Message processed in 102ms - com.example.product.module.Receiver#130
2015-08-01 12:25:21.226 | DEBUG | Thread-12 | Message processed in 103ms - com.example.product.module.Receiver#130
```

I crafted a regular expression which is able to perform matches on the 'rearranged' log:

```
/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}).*(Thread-\d+).*Received message with id (\d+) [\s\S]+?\2.*Message processed in (\d+)ms/g
```

The desired result when printing the captured groups (`print "$1;$2;$3;$4\n";`) is:

```
2015-08-01 12:23:21.123;Thread-10;1234;101
2015-08-01 12:24:21.123;Thread-11;2345;102
2015-08-01 12:25:21.123;Thread-12;3456;103
```

When i use www.regexr.com to try those examples, the run on the rearranged log snipped gives three matches.

My first problem now is: when i want to use the regex in an Perl one-liner i am not able to perform the match over the multiple lines. I think it has something to do with the -n switch which causes to add a loop around the perl code, and the perl code being executed on each line separately.

`cat files.log | perl -ne 'next LINE unless /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}).*(Thread-\d+).*Received message with id (\d+) [\s\S]+?\2.*Message processed in (\d+)ms/gm; print "$1;$2;$3;$4\n";'`

The second problem i face is, that on the real log files where the log files are not so nicely arranged i can not extract all possible matches. In the given snipped it is only possible to match one result, not all three which are there.

I tried things like setting the record seperator in the Perl command to undef `$\=undef;`, remove the `next LINE unless`...

Can anybody point me in a direction which might help?

The logfiles can get rather big (~200mb), so combining all line into one huge String does not seem to be a good approach, although i haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are usually used for grouping.

```
my %buf;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split / \| /;
   my $id = $fields[2];
   push @{ $buf{$id} }, \@fields;
   process(@{ delete($buf{$id}) })
      if $fields[3] =~ /^Message processed in /;
}
```

`process` is called for each group of rows. Each of `process`'s parameters is a row, as a reference to an array of fields.

Comment: i did not try this Perl script, but i expect a very different result like the desired CSV formatted one...

Comment: The question at hand is about grouping the records by thread. Are you saying you also problems outputting a CSV? You should have started by using Text::CSV_XS. If you have problems with the module, post a proper question with your work and your problem.

Comment: well, i am not a Perl hacker, i just use Perl occasionally for extracting data from logfiles using regular expressions. Which is very handy and i hoped that extracting data which span over multiple lines is also not too complicated using Perl and regex. And the CVS file i usually create by piping the STDOUT of perl to a file. I never used a special module for it.
I tried your script now, and it terminates with a syntax error at line 6, near "push"

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We help people with their programming problems. You came with a problem grouping records, and I've provided a solution. If you have any questions about it, I'll be happy to answer them. I don't know why you're still talking about CSV.

Comment: I am pretty aware that SO is not a code writing service. But i want to learn something new regarding regex and how Perl applies them when data is feeded via STDIN. I personally like regex but unfortunately i am not very used to them :)

Comment: The regex match operator doesn't care from where the data in the scalar being matched came.

Comment: Re "I tried your script now, and it terminates with a syntax error at line 6, near 'push'", Just noticed your edit. It was because of a missing semi-colon I've already fixed.

Comment: the script runs now. It dies after a while with "Out of memory!" with smaller logfiles it does not die, but it shows no results. I assume thats because the script does not output anything. I tried to find `process` in perldoc, but i did not find it...

Comment: Oops, fixed. Was checking if the line started with `Message processed in ` rather than fourth field. // `process` is for you to write. It's called for each group of rows to do with as you please. You said something about outputting CSV...

Comment: now i get the following error:
`Undefined subroutine &main::process called at t.pl line 7, <> line 8370.`

Comment: I repeat: `process` is for you to write. It's called for each group of rows to do with as you please. You said something about outputting CSV...

Comment: well, i did not see the reference that i need to write a "process" function... As i said earlier, i am not a Perl hacker :)